# Generalisation of Farkas Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I want to use Farkas lemma, but with a different minimal bound than 0.

(I use the "same definition as in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma).)

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ then exactly one of the following two statements is true:

1. There exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=b$ and $x\geq c$
2. There exists a $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that ???

I tried the generalized version on wikipedia, but unfortunately $\{x\geq c\}$ is not a cone.

$c$ can be interpreted as a real number and the inequality is meant component wise. But the more general version where $c$ is a vector would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $z=x-c$. Your first statement is
$$Az=b-Ac\;\mbox{ and }\;z\geq0.$$
Hence, the second one should be
$$A^Ty\geq0\;\mbox{ and }\;(b-Ac)^Ty<0.$$